# Simple Java hash map with weak keys based on identity in Google Guava?

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, identity, weak-references

I need a simple hash map with weak keys. Java's own `WeakHashMap` gives me that, but not with identity semantics (it uses `equals()` for key comparison).

Google's Guava library has revamped its hash map methods. In the latest version (14.0), instead of using a `MapMaker` (which has many if not most things deprecated), I apparently should now use a `CacheBuilder`, which all sorts of options. Fine, it has a `weakKeys()` option, so that's what I'll use. But the resulting cache is also concurrent (i.e. it keeps various maps inside and uses its own internal set of keys to regulate access concurrently), and I can't turn that off; I don't need concurrency, as I'm already using my own `ReadWriteLock` to govern access to my map.

Fine, I'll accept concurrency; just give me the map! I try:

```
Map<Foo, Bar> map = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().weakKeys().build();
```

Wait, that gives me back a `Cache<Object, Object>`, which isn't a `Map<Foo, Bar>`! How can I get a simple identity-based weakly-keyed map in Google Guava?

Comment: Have you combined Guava Map with java.lang.ref.WeakReference<T>?

Comment: This might interest you : http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/lucene/lucene-3.6.1/org/apache/lucene/util/WeakIdentityMap.java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're willing to live with concurrency, you're almost there:

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder().weakKeys().build().asMap();
```

But that said...your use case isn't entirely clear, that is, *why* you need a map with these properties, and why you need a map with identity semantics when the keys have another notion of equality.

Comment: So is this meant to replace `new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap()` (i.e. I'm not getting some extra caching stuff without wanting it), or is the `MapMaker` version somehow different? And if they are the same, is `MapMaker` now deprecated in all aspects?

Comment: @GarretWilson: I think `MapMaker` is still fine for just making a `Map` like you want. You may also want to use `concurrencyLevel(1)` to minimize the concurrency overhead.

Comment: @ColinD I think the `concurrencyLevel` will not even make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @GarretWilson "is `MapMaker` now deprecated in all aspects?" ... just look at the docs. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html  (There is one deprecated method, `softValues`.)

Comment: @KevinBourrillion right, need to use: `.<Foo, Bar>build()`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Where did you say/set something about identity?

Answer (score 2):

> I need a simple hash map with weak keys.

I don't follow why you want to switch from `MapMaker` to `CacheBuilder` then. It sounds like what you want is what `MapMaker` is there for.

You may not think you need concurrency, but remember that GC can run concurrently, and cause stale entries to be cleaned up. Anyway, the concurrency won't even cost you much.

Comment: I've edited the question to be clearer that it was my understanding from the documentation that Guava wants me to switch to `CacheBuilder`, as it deprecated so much of `MapMaker`. If `MapMaker` is still find to use for certain situations, that's fine with me. And I don't think the concurrency I was talking about is the same thing you're talking about, as the GC's releasing of weak references happens without the need to add any sort of extra multithreaded support to the application (e.g. a single thread doesn't need a lock to access a `WeakReference`).

Comment: @GarretWilson When that weak reference is cleared, something has to cause the entry to get cleaned up from the map. That something can happen concurrently to your application threads.

Comment: This is not necessarily what happens in `WeakHashMap`, and that's not the same thing as the "concurrency" in the sense of `MapMaker` and `CacheBuilder`. `WeakHashMap` synchronizes on its queue whenever it expunges expired references---but this doesn't make `WeakHashMap` "concurrent" (it is fail-safe and throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`). `ConcurrentHashMap` (and things produced by `MapMaker`) bring true concurrency for multi-thread access by essentially maintaining multiple maps internally---something I don't need or want if I control access at a higher level using read/write locks.

Comment: Kevin's right, this is a great use of `MapMaker`. Note that only a subset of the old `MapMaker` was deprecated in favor of `CacheBuilder`. This use case is exactly what `MapMaker` will remain around for.

Comment: Regarding concurrency, both `MapMaker` and `CacheBuilder` would support `concurrencyLevel(1)`, which basically gets rid of the concurrency memory overhead by having a single internal segment.

Comment: Charles gave me an off-line education. My comments were based on an *old* implementation of `MapMaker`, which performed cleanup on GC threads. It doesn't do that anymore, so never mind!